# web application that supports in all the browsers?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I am using GWT/Spring to develop web applications. currently my appln supports only IE7. it also supports other browsers like firefox. but alignments are changed across the browsers. how can make the web application view is same in all the browsers? PLease help me.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is what you customized till now. In general it's about applying CSS try-and-error approach.

Comment: Do you use _standard mode_ or _quirks mode_? Are you using _layout panels_? Finally, you won't achieve pixel-perfect rendering in all browsers, and users won't mind: only developers use several browsers and compare results between them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no silver bullet in terms of cross browser compatibility. This is a huge area and highly dependent on the specific HTML and CSS you developed for your application. Going for that "pixel perfect" compatibility can easily eat up hours and hours in tweaking and is often not worth the effort. Like Piyush mentioned, it might be more productive to make sure your site looks nice (not broken layout) in the browsers you are looking to support rather than trying to make it look identical everywhere.

Best advice I can give you is to adhere to HTML standards (which tags can be nested inside which etc), use CSS for styling, don't over-use tables unless you absolutely have to and don't create layouts that will break if one element is a pixel off (like moving a an inline div to a new line just because it rendered 101 pixels wide instead of 100).

EDIT: this is a very useful little javascript library I have used on several occasions, http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/. What it does is to add classes to your `<html>` element based on the browser. That way, you can create specific CSS to target a single (or family) of browsers for those exceptional cases where you have to go in and style specifically for one browser.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo is a nice UI library to look at...

Although, JQuery is more known for its browser support, dojo is much simpler.

But in general, there is no method without hardcoding for each browser to display things exactly the same. The point in browser support is to have a nice interface for all browsers rather than the exact same interface. In General, you will be fine as long as you use a strict HTML standard.

Hope this Helps

Comment: GWT is a nice product too, and one the OP says it is using right now. I doubt switching from GWT to any JS library would solve the issue.

Comment: true.. I only suggested this as a completely UI based solution as it does not have much serverside dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I also have a GWT-Spring application . I use EXT-GWT  - GXT from Sencha . GWT basically compiles the components for different browsers .

The

```
    <module>
      <set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8,ie6" />
    </module>
```

compiles the code for different browsers . But as is common with all apps , We use different css for different browsers and tweak these as necessary . There are quite few javascript libraries that would help you but you may come across integration issues with GWT .

Answer (score -1):

JQuery might be helpful for you, but remember 100% cross browser support without some dirty tweaking is really hard to achieve..

[this is a nice link](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) for cross browser jQuery support

Comment: The OP says he's using GWT already; if he's unable to make a cross-browser app with GWT, switching to jQuery won't help (possibly quite the contrary actually)